# Nginx VirtualHosts with Subdomains always directs to primary domain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, subdomain

I have two sites running as below.
Server : nginx/1.14.2 / Debian 10

- primary site `mydomain.com` in `/var/www/mydomain` directory
- sub site `blog.mydomain.com` in /var/www/blog` directory

See DNS entries.

```
Type    Name          Content       TTL 
A       blog          34.72.11.9    auto
A       mydomain.com  34.72.11.9    auto
CNAME   www           mydomain.com  auto
```

Configured nginx virtual host seperately

```
server_name  mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
```

and

```
server_name  sub1.mydomain.com
```

But, blog.mydomain.com also loading with mydomain.com content.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't leave comments, I need four more reputation points but I may be able to help.

With the information you have provided it's difficult to figure out but as a guide I do the following. I use Nginx as a reverse proxy which caches an Apache on another server but the config should be the same.

Before mucking around with your nginx configuration make certain you do a backup. I am also assuming you are on a Linux machine not windows.

In my nginx.conf with the http block;

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Each domain has its own config for easier debugging, for example /etx/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf

```
server {

    listen 192.168.0.100:80;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com;
    index index.html index.php;

}
```

Now for /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.mydomain.com.conf;

```
server {

        listen 192.168.0.100:80;

        server_name blog.mydomain.com;
        root /var/www/blog.mydomain.com;
        index index.html index.php;

    }
```

Now tell nginx to test the configuration and then reload.

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

If the above doesn't work make sure there are no other "server" blocks overriding and that "default_server" is not set anywhere. Ensure proper file ownership and access rights and that the nginx user can read the required files.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Yes, I am following the same pattern; different sites are kept as different files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name blog.mydomain.com;

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules in your setup that might redirect to mydomain.com? If you are using firefox or google chrome you can right click on page and select inspect. Refresh the page and select the "Network" in the inspector. Is there anything odd about headers & responses? Could it be cached in your browser? Lots of questions but I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Yes, I am following the same pattern; different sites are kept as different files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

`default_server` is there in `default` config but not activated. (not in sites-enabled)

$ grep -R default_server ./../
./../sites-available/default:   listen 80 default_server;
./../sites-available/default:   listen [::]:80 default_server;
./../sites-available/default:   # listen 443 ssl default_server;
./../sites-available/default:   # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

Comment: This is my subdomain config

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name blog.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}

Comment: @Gineesh quick question, do you actually have an IPV6 address to listen on. Probably not important but I remember reading something about listening when it doesn't exist.

Comment: oh okay. Yea tried by disabling the same. but no luck.

Comment: @Gineesh If you temporarily comment out "include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;" and reload nginx and see what happens. Does it still go to mydomain.com? Just checking if there is something in an included file redirecting.

Comment: btw, I have other domains hosted on same server under diff `/var/www/` directories and diff config files. All those are working. Only subdomain not working as its redirecting to parent (main domain) site. Tried different sites and diff subdomains.. and cleared cahce multiple times.. ;(

Comment: yes, removed all those php, logs, but didnt help ;(

Comment: @Gineesh Can you confirm the symbolic link for blog.mydomain.com.conf points to the correct file and not mydomain.com.conf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106934/discussion-between-gineesh-and-admiral-noisy-bottom).

Comment: Very useful, thanks. It worked for me right away. The names were a bit confusing, so I submitted an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Yogesch Well spotted on the typing errors and thanks for fixing them.